# Jenkins Jetty redirect http to https

Tags: jenkins, https, jetty

We set our Jenkins ver. 2.150.1 running on a default Jetty (Ubuntu) with https on port 8443. Is it possible to redirect all access from http(8080) to https(8443) without Apache/Nginx proxy? It would be great to use an existing Jetty.

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented but it could be possible using SecuredRedirectHandler.
Please note this is development is part of Jenkins project: https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone/.
You can propose a pull request with the change and I will be happy to review/merge
Or at least log a change request here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS.